# Extract a node from xml response

Tags: c#, xml

Below is my response generated from a webservice.
I want to do such that I want only `PresentationElements` node from this response.
Any help how can I achieve this query?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GetContentResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ExtensionData />
  <GetContentResult>
    <ExtensionData />
    <Code>0</Code>
    <Value>Success</Value>
  </GetContentResult>
  <PresentationElements>
    <PresentationElement>
      <ExtensionData />
      <ContentReference>Product View Pack</ContentReference>
      <ID>SHOPPING_ELEMENT:10400044</ID>
      <Name>View Pack PE</Name>
      <PresentationContents>
        <PresentationContent>
          <ExtensionData />
          <Content>View Pack</Content>
          <ContentType>TEXT</ContentType>
          <Language>ENGLISH</Language>
          <Medium>COMPUTER_BROWSER</Medium>
          <Name>Name</Name>
        </PresentationContent>
        <PresentationContent>
          <ExtensionData />
          <Content>Have more control of your home's security and lighting with View Pack from XFINITY Home.</Content>
          <ContentType>TEXT</ContentType>
          <Language>ENGLISH</Language>
          <Medium>COMPUTER_BROWSER</Medium>
          <Name>Description</Name>
        </PresentationContent>
        <PresentationContent>
          <ExtensionData />
          <Content>/images/shopping/devices/xh/view-pack-2.jpg</Content>
          <ContentType>TEXT</ContentType>
          <Language>ENGLISH</Language>
          <Medium>COMPUTER_BROWSER</Medium>
          <Name>Image</Name>
        </PresentationContent>
        <PresentationContent>
          <ExtensionData />
          <Content>The View Pack includes:
2 Lighting / Appliance Controllers
2 Indoor / Outdoor Cameras</Content>
          <ContentType>TEXT</ContentType>
          <Language>ENGLISH</Language>
          <Medium>COMPUTER_BROWSER</Medium>
          <Name>Feature1</Name>
        </PresentationContent>
      </PresentationContents>
    </PresentationElement>
  </PresentationElements>
</GetContentResponse>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty easy, have you tried:

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("... xml");
var nodes = (from n in xml.Descendants("PresentationElements")
                        select n).ToList();
```

You could also project each individual node to an anonymous type using something like:

```
select new 
{
  ContentReference = (string)n.Element("ContentReference").Value,
  .... etc
}
```

Comment: have tried the above solution.. but it returns an IEnumerable. so that causes issues. may be i am not casting it .ToList()

Comment: Yes, you have to enumerate it by calling `ToList()` or `ToArray()`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use XPath extensions

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(response);
XElement presentations = xdoc.XPathSelectElement("//PresentationElements");
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use the `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument`:

```
//Initialize the XDocument
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(yourString);

//your query
var desiredNodes = doc.Descendants("PresentationElements");
```

Comment: Maybe downvoted because it's not a file, but a response from a service; but I can only guess.

Comment: Maybe downvoter should know that you can create XDocument instance from string but not only from file. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345532.aspx